# How do you output the filename in find command while using -exec?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, find

I use the following line to find all sub-directories of the PWD and run `svnadmin verify` on each directory (I already know that they're Subversion repositories)

```
find ./* -maxdepth 0 -exec svnadmin verify {} \;
```

This works well, other than the fact that the output looks like this:

```
* Verifying repository metadata ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 1 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 2 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 4 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 5 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 6 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 9 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 10 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 12 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 14 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 15 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 18 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 20 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 22 ...
* Verified revision 0.
* Verified revision 1.
* Verified revision 2.
* Verified revision 3.
* Verified revision 4.
* Verified revision 5.
* Verified revision 6.
* Verified revision 7.
* Verified revision 8.
* Verified revision 9.
* Verified revision 10.
* Verified revision 11.
* Verified revision 12.
* Verified revision 13.
* Verified revision 14.
* Verified revision 15.
* Verified revision 16.
* Verified revision 17.
* Verified revision 18.
* Verified revision 19.
* Verified revision 20.
* Verified revision 21.
* Verified revision 22.
* Verified revision 23.
* Verified revision 0.
* Verifying repository metadata ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 4 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 5 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 6 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 7 ...
* Verifying metadata at revision 9 ...
* Verified revision 0.
* Verified revision 1.
* Verified revision 2.
* Verified revision 3.
* Verified revision 4.
* Verified revision 5.
* Verified revision 6.
* Verified revision 7.
* Verified revision 8.
* Verified revision 9.
```

I'd really like `find` to print the filename before executing the `svnadmin verify` command, to make logging easier.

I've tried to squeeze a little `ls` in there but bodged it up, how should I do this (preferably simply)?

Comment: Use `xargs --verbose` instead. It will **print the command before executing it!** See with your example here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1241661/670392

Answer (score 78, accepted):

simply add a `-printf` option before

```
find -printf '%p' -exec command \;
```

Comment: Lovely, I changed `'%p'` to `'%p\n'` so that the name precedes the verify output on it's own line.

Comment: @Arronical if that's the format you want, you could replace the (formatted) `-printf '%p\n'` with the simpler `-print`

Comment: `find  -name <a_name> -print -exec command {} \;`

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to recurse, there's no point in using `find` in this case. It is far simpler to do it in the shell directly:

```
for d in */; do echo "$d"; svnadmin verify "$d"; done
```

The `for d in */` will find all directories (the `*/` ensures only directories and no files are found); the `echo "$d"` will print the directory's name; the
`svnadmin verify "$d"` will check the directory.

This can be run either directly from the command line or from within a script with no change in format.

Comment: This does look like a better way to achieve my goal, but I had to give the answer to Fiximan just because my title and question reference `find` so much. Thanks for improving my knowledge though!

Comment: This requires using a glob. Globbing is definitely useful & powerful, but in my personal experience the syntax is more difficult to set up, and often ends up needing other things like `dotglob` and `globstar` in bash, which creates a longer, more complicated script. I tend to save globs for large complicated tasks, while `find`'s syntax is easier to throw together on the fly by just stringing together a bunch of filters and commands into a one-liner.

Comment: @user5359531 neither globstar nor dotglob (unless you know you have hidden files and actually want them) are needed here. This is obviously a matter of opinion but you are the first person I've ever come across who considers the rather obtuse format of `find` simpler. I always prefer globs over `find` since I not only find them far simpler but they are also safer when dealing with arbitrary filenames that are passed to other programs.

Comment: there are certainly use-cases to use `find` over shell globing beyond directory recursion, like using predicates

Comment: @CervEd of course, I was only referring to the specific problem mentioned here. There are loads of cases where `find` would be the right tool, it's just that this specific one isn't one of them. I added an "in this case" to clarify that I wasn't making a general statement.

Answer (score 10):

```
find ./* -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec bash -c 'echo "{}"; svnadmin verify "{}"' \;
```

I have added `-type d` if it is only directories.

Comment: I'd quote `{}`, at least in `svnadmin verify {}`

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. So in this command does the `-exec` spawn a child shell,  in which the 2 commands are run, using `;` as end of line?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
for f in * ; do echo  -n "${f}:"; svnadmin verify "${f}"; done
```

If you just want directories(Thanks to @kos note):

```
for f in */ ; do echo  -n "${f}:"; svnadmin verify "${f}"; done
```

Comment: Nice, but this will process also files: `for f in */` will process only directories

Comment: Will this only work in a script? Or can I issue it on the command line?

Comment: @Arronical will work also as command line

Answer (score 3):

- Use `. -maxdepth 1` instead of `./*`, you need only the first level in the folder structure
- Use `-type d`, you need only folders
- Use `! -name "."`, you don't need `.`
- Use `-exec` to start a shell
- Use `sh -c` to start commands inside the shell

*Your command*

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "." -exec sh -c 'echo "{}"; svnadmin verify "{}"' \;
```

---

or shorter

- Use `-prune` if the file is a directory, do not descend into it

*Your command*

```
find . -mindepth 1 -prune -exec sh -c 'echo "{}"; svnadmin verify "{}"' \;
```

Comment: `-prune` looks interesting. I used `./* -maxdepth 0` to avoid returning `.` from the find command. It doesn't cause any critical error, but I prefer not to have that in my output.

Answer (score 1):

`find` has option flags for printing, which  are already mentioned in other answers. If we look at the problem form the perspective of executing multiple commands for the same currently processed file, `find` allows using multiple `-exec` statements. This means we could opt for using:

```
find ./* -maxdepth 0 -exec echo {} \; -exec svnadmin verify {} \;
```

Again, note that this approach is applicable to not just printing with `echo`, `printf`, or other utilities, but also other commands.

Answer (score 1):

This will print the name and contents of files-only recursively..

```
find . -type f -printf '\n\n%p:\n' -exec cat {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Best use find with ***XARGS***, as it has verbose option exactly for this:

```
xargs --verbose / -t
      Print the command line on the standard error output before executing it.
```

So in your example:

```
find ./* -maxdepth 0 -type d | xargs -n1 --verbose svnadmin verify

svnadmin verify ./REPO_DIR_A
* Verified revision ...
svnadmin verify ./REPO_DIR_B
* Verified revision ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to pipe the `find` output to `read` loop:

```
find . | while read d; do echo "=== ${d}: ==="; svnadmin verify ${d}; done
```

It allows you to execute more complicated, compound command sequence with filenames returned by `find`, like in this fancy `ls` example:

```
find . | while read f; do echo ${f} | figlet -k; done
```