# How to script Subversion verification?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Leading on from this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/651315/320386), I'm trying to write a bash script which will recurse two directories from the directory containing my subversion repositories, checking whether directories are repositories. There will be a mix of directories and repositories, and some repos hiding in those sub-dirs.

Any Subversion repos discovered should have their name printed to an output file, followed by the output of `svnadmin verify`.

I have the following snippet to check whether a directory is a repository:

```
svnlook info /path/to/repo >/dev/null
```

So I'm throwing away the `svnlook` output, a return code of 0 indicates that it is indeed a SVN repo. I could use this snippet, in an `if` statement to run `svnadmin verify` if 0 is returned.

I've tried:

```
find /dir/containing/repos -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec bash -c 'if [ "svnlook info {} >/dev/null" = 0 ] ;then ;echo "{}" >>output.txt ;svnadmin verify "{}" >>output.txt ;fi' \;
```

Though I get the following warning for each directory found:

```
bash: -c: -line 0: syntax error near unexpected token ';'
```

I think I'm trying to unnecessarily cram it all into one `find` command, which I'm getting wrong anyway. What would be the best way to structure this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `;` after `then` in `then ;echo "{}" >>output.txt`.

Use :

```
then echo "{}" >>output.txt
```

Also note that rather than playing with `{}` use positional parameters of shell (i am not familiar with `svn` so relying upon your commands) :

```
find /dir/containing/repos -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec bash -c 'if svnlook info /path/to/repo >/dev/null ;then echo "$1" >>output.txt ;svnadmin verify "$1" >>output.txt ;fi' _ {} \;
```

- `if svnlook info /path/to/repo >/dev/null` will run the command and redirect the STDOUT to `/dev/null`
- If the `svnlook info /path/to/repo` command is successful (exit code 0), then `echo "$1" >>output.txt ;svnadmin verify "$1" >>output.txt` commands will be run
- Here we are using the directory names `{}` as the fist argument (`$1`) to be processed by shell.
- `_` here is just a placeholder indicating positional parameter 0 as `bash -c command` starts considering any further argument after the `command` starting from 0. As `_` is the zero-th argument, we can use `{}` as the first argument. Check `man bash` to get more idea.

Comment: Thanks again, it turns out that I also needed a `&` in `svnadmin verify "$1"  &>>output.txt` to get what I wanted from the command, and used `"$1"` to replace the `/path/to/repo` part for `svnlook`. What does the `_` do near the end of line?

Comment: @Arronical Glad i could help..check my edits..