# Get a script variable into subshell launched by find

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables, find

Following on from this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/651680/320386) I've used the following command in a bash script:

```
find ${svn_root} -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec bash -c 'if svnlook info "$1" &>/dev/null ;then echo"$1" >>${log_file} ;svnadmin verify "$1" 2>>{log_file} ;fi' _ {} \;
```

Both variables are defined at the beginning of the script. The variable $svn_root is appropriately expanded, but the $log_file variable is not.

I see that the variable is not passed into any of the `-exec bash -c` command, I assume that's because it's a subshell?
I can slip `log_file=/path/to/log ;` in front of the `echo` part of the line, but that kind of hard codes that part of the command, if I change the variable in the script without changing it within the find command I'll be outputting to two separate log files!

Can I import/export that variable into that subshell (if that's what it is)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are mainly two ways:

1. Pass it as a second argument to the shell

   ```
   find ... -exec bash -c '...' _ {} "$log_file" \;
   ```

And then you use `"$2"` instead of `${log_file}` inside the script

2. Pass it via the environment:

   ```
   log_file=$log_file find ... -exec bash -c '...' _ {} \;
   ```

BTW, it's not a subshell.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to see such variables in your subshell if you used double quotes with `bash -c ""`.

A simpler method would be to just `export` the `log_file` variable in your main script as follow:

```
export log_file
```

Source: [How to “send” variable to sub-shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23179/how-to-send-variable-to-sub-shell)

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
find ${svn_root} -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec bash -c 'if svnlook info "$0" &>/dev/null ;then echo"$0" >> "$1" ;svnadmin verify "$0" 2>> "$1" ;fi' {}  "$log_file" \;
```

You need `$0` and `$1`, because this is not a function or a script.

Comment: I was a bit confused before the edit!

Comment: @Arronical Yes, I'm know. I'm on mobile, that's difficult :)

Comment: I've tried using a phone a couple of times, tough stuff ;)