# Find recursively in folders, subfolders and multiple files

Tags: command-line, find

I want to find all `html` files and only show the file names, not the full file path, what I tried:

```
find /home/irakli/Desktop/irakli_linux -print | grep -i '.*[.]html'
```

Results:

```
/home/irakli/Desktop/irakli_linux/htmll/10.html
/home/irakli/Desktop/irakli_linux/htmll/11.html
/home/irakli/Desktop/irakli_linux/htmll/12.html
/home/irakli/Desktop/irakli_linux/htmll/13.html
/home/irakli/Desktop/irakli_linux/htmll/14.html
/home/irakli/Desktop/irakli_linux/htmll/15.html
```

I only want  `1.html 2.html` ...

Comment: @Sergiy I doubt this is a duplicate of [How to Search for Files Recursively into Subdirectories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307876/how-to-search-for-files-recursively-into-subdirectories). This one particularly asks how to print just the filename (without the path) while the other one asks for `find` in general.

Comment: @PerlDuck  Admittedly, the many top answers don't mention printing only filename without path, however  IMHO it's a matter of reading the manual and adding proper flag to the command. I have, however, edited my own answer there to mention some of the flags `find` has, so hopefully that covers it.  Alternatively, https://askubuntu.com/a/651321/295286 would probably be a more appropriate, and it pretty much same question in the title. Feel free to vote on reopening, though.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Congrats on `command-line` gold :) This seems more of a duplicate for printing basename only?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Hi, thanks. I've had `command-line` gold for about 2-3 years now.  Check the list of duplicates to this post - there's two, [How do you output the filename in find command while using -exec?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651315/how-do-you-output-the-filename-in-find-command-while-using-exec) addresses that issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to use `grep`, `find` can do exactly what you seek.

Use:

```
find  -iname "*.html" -printf "%f\n"
```

It will look for all `html` files and only prints out their name.

If you want all names at the same line:

```
find  -iname "*.html" -printf "%f "
```

Comment: It's works, can you please tell me what's is %f\n?

Comment: `%f` file name, `\n`, a new line.

Comment: @Irakli See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/find.1.html and scroll down to `-printf`. There are various other %something flags you can use, e.g. %s for the file's size.

Comment: `"%f\n"` maybe better in case some filenames have spaces in them.